# Trouble grabbing lisp input from the web using hunchentoot and sbcl

Tags: lisp, sbcl, hunchentoot

A lisp question here. I've been slowly learning lisp over the last couple of months and have ran into a problem when trying to grab input from a web browser vs. grabbing input from a REPL.

The specific problem is when trying to evaluate this code:

Assume `sexp` is `'(look north)`.

`(member (car sexp) '(look walk pickup drop))`

From the REPL in SBCL this works fine and as expected. However, when grabbing the `sexp` from hunchentoot even though `sexp` "looks" like it is the same as from the REPL it never seems to be able to consider the result of `(car sexp)` a member of `'(look walk pickup drop)`.

I think it might be the character encoding of the file vs. character encoding of `sexp` when grabbed from the web browser but I have no idea how to test this hypothesis. Any pointers would be much appreciated!

### Edit

The way I take the input in is based on based on the text adventure game from "Land of Lisp" by Conrad Barski and is detailed below.

```
(defun game-read (string-to-read)
  (let ((cmd (read-from-string
               (concatenate 'string "(" string-to-read ")"))))
    (describe cmd)
    (flet ((quote-it (x)
                     (list 'quote x)))
      (cons (car cmd) (mapcar #'quote-it (cdr cmd))))))
```

This is then wrapped in:

```
(defun game-eval (sexp)
  (if (member (car sexp) *allowed-commands*) ;Offending line                                                                          
      (eval sexp)
      '(i do not know that command.)))
```

where `*allowed-commands*` is:

```
(defparameter *allowed-commands* '(look walk pickup inventory))
```

The line that I have labelled as offending the one that works fine normally but when the `string-to-read` is from a request parameter fetched from hunchentoot as part of a request `(car sexp)` *looks* the same any way I know how to look at it but is not found in `*allowed-commands*`.

Comment: You should show how you "grab" that input.

Comment: You're right! Corrected!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure what the input is you get. Is it a symbol? Common Lisp has functions like TYPE-OF, INSPECT and DESCRIBE to get more information about data.

```
* (describe 'north)

COMMON-LISP-USER::NORTH
  [symbol]


* (type-of 'north)

SYMBOL
```

The next question is: if it is a symbol, in which package is it?

```
* (symbol-package 'north)

#<PACKAGE "COMMON-LISP-USER">
```

Are your other symbols in the same package?

The next question is: if it is a symbol or a string, how about capitalization?

```
* (symbol-name 'north)

"NORTH"
```

By default symbols are uppercase. That needs not be the case for your symbols read from input.

Now you can also play with MEMBER to make pure string comparisons:

```
* (member (symbol-name '|Foo|)
          '(foo bar baz)
          :key #'symbol-name :test #'equalp)

(FOO BAR BAZ)   ; this is the usual return value,
                ; the rest list with first item found
```

Comment: Thanks! This is pretty handy! Unfortunately the `describe`, `type-of` and `inspect` functions all give the same output... Using `describe` I get a list as the type and `type-of` a CONS, which I *think* is expected. Weirdly in my `game-eval` function when my `member` function key parameter `:test` is the value `#'string-equal` it does find the member in `*allowed-commands*`! It does not find the function though, saying that the function `LOOK` is undefined. Almost there!

Comment: I figured out what it was. Turns out the lisp reader was spoiling me, as well as a packaging issue. Selected this one as the correct answer as it allowed me to check out how everything was looking and where everything was.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used sbcl or Common Lisp, but this sounds like an interning problem. Try this query instead:

```
(member (intern (car sexp)) '(look walk pickup drop)))
```